# Is CA1309 still valid for source compiled against .NET 4.5.1?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, fxcop

When we enabled fxcop with a superset of the "Microsoft All Rules" ruleset for one of our projects it also enabled CA1309 and immediately started complaining about constructions such as this:

```
if (translationItem.Description == "Description")
```

Showing warnings such as:

[image]
When looking at the reference source for `string` [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs), it shows that the `operator ==` uses `String.Equals` which in turn uses `EqualsHelper`. When calling the `Equals` overload proposed by CA1309, the same `EqualsHelper` is called. Hence, it seems like the `==` operator already uses Ordinal comparison.

So my question is, should we refactor the snippet above into this:

```
if (string.Equals(translationItem.Description, "Description", StringComparison.Ordinal))
```

And if so, why should we?

P.S. We do really intend to use a case-sensitive string compare in the above snippets.

P.S.2. We use the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers` nuget package to run code analysis on-the-fly.

Comment: Is the property (or field) `.Description` declared as `object` or some interface type? _Edit:_ Equivalently, when you rest the mouse over the `==` token in your code, does a tool tip show `bool object.operator ==(object left, object right)`?

Comment: It's a string property

Comment: With the string property declared as `public string Description { get; set; }`, comparison using the `==` operator, and the "Microsoft All Rules" ruleset in VS Pro 2015 Update 3, I'm not getting the warning. Are you sure the warning refers to the line of code you think it does?

Comment: Ah, right, I forgot to mention we enabled a few more rules on top of the "Microsoft All Rules" set, which includes CA1309 it seems, will update the question. I'm using VS Enterprise 2015 Update 3.

Comment: @Vincent The Professional edition and its "All Rules" ruleset include that rule as well.

Comment: Please see the screenshot I've attached to the question, it's really that line it's complaining about. (Yes, I created a console app so I could take a screenshot without disclosing source) And when I just select "Microsoft All Rules", the CA1309 is not enabled under CSharp.Analyzers.

Comment: I can confirm that the rule from the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers` NuGet package is in fact triggered while the same rule from the built-in VS Code Analysis feature is not. The NuGet package seems to be a preview - why not open an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much of an answer but, per request of cynic from the comments, [an issue has been raised over at the roslyn github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/1081). The issue has been resolved and closed and the fix will be released with milestone [15.3](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/milestone/5).